# Resetting numerical labels in \foreach commands on a numberline

Tags: tikz-pgf, numbering, foreach

I am looking to create quick number lines. What I have so far is this:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes,backgrounds,arrows}   
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1pt,line cap=round,x=.5cm,y=.5cm]
                        \clip (0,-0.8) rectangle (10,1);
                        %   Inequality Line
                        \draw   [<->,thick]     (0,0) -- (10,0);
                        %   Tick Marks
                        \foreach \x in {1,2,...,9}
                        \draw (\x,-2pt) -- (\x,2pt) node [anchor=north,below=3pt] {$\scriptstyle \x$};
                        %   Displayed Solution
\end{tikzpicture}               
\end{document}
```

What I am looking for is to change the loop of x-intervals to start at a different number.

For instance, I want to first number on the number line to be 8, then 9, 10, 11 resepectively, not 1,2,3,etc; but I can't find any answers that will help me with this. I imagine there is an simple mathematical formula to do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first example code below presents three options to achieve the desired result:

1. Using `\numexpr` (useful only to perform integer basic arithmetics).
2. Using the `evaluate= <variable> as <macro> using <formula>` syntax (this also involves a change in the precision, to avoid the decimal separator and extra digits).
3. Using `count=<macro> from <value>`.

For more information on the second and third options, see subsection **Options to customize the foreach-statement** (page 508) of the pgfmanual:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1pt,line cap=round,x=.5cm,y=.5cm]
\draw[<->,thick] (0,0) -- (10,0);
\foreach \x  in {1,2,...,9}
  \draw (\x,-2pt) -- (\x,2pt) 
    node [anchor=north,below=3pt]   {$\scriptstyle\the\numexpr\x+8\relax$};
\begin{scope}[yshift=-1cm,/pgf/number format/.cd,precision=0]
\draw[<->,red,thick] (0,0) -- (10,0);
\foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \xeval using \x+8] in {1,2,...,9}
  \draw (\x,-2pt) -- (\x,2pt) 
    node [anchor=north,below=3pt] {$\scriptstyle\pgfmathprintnumber{\xeval}$};
\end{scope}               
\begin{scope}[yshift=-2cm]
\draw[<->,blue,thick] (0,0) -- (10,0);
\foreach \x [count=\xi from 9] in {1,2,...,9}
  \draw (\x,-2pt) -- (\x,2pt) 
    node [anchor=north,below=3pt] {$\scriptstyle\xi$};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}               

\end{document}
```

[image]

In the case required in the question all three approaches mentioned produce the same result; however, the `evaluate= <variable> as <macro> using <formula>` syntax can be used in case that more complex operations are involved; a little example:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1pt,line cap=round,x=.5cm,y=.5cm,/pgf/number format/.cd,precision=1]
\draw[<->,thick] (0,0) -- (10,0);
\foreach \x  in {1,2,...,9}
  \draw (\x,-2pt) -- (\x,2pt) 
    node [anchor=north,below=3pt]   {$\scriptstyle\the\numexpr\x+8\relax$};
\begin{scope}[yshift=-1cm]
\draw[<->,red,thick] (0,0) -- (10,0);
\foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \xeval using 1.5*\x] in {1,2,...,9}
  \draw (\x,-2pt) -- (\x,2pt) 
    node [anchor=north,below=3pt] {$\scriptstyle\pgfmathprintnumber{\xeval}$};
\end{scope}               
\begin{scope}[yshift=-2cm,x=1.2cm,y=.5cm]
\draw[<->,blue,thick] (0,0) -- (10,0);
\foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \xeval using e^(\x)] in {1,2,...,9}
  \draw (\x,-2pt) -- (\x,2pt) 
    node [anchor=north,below=3pt] {$\scriptstyle\pgfmathprintnumber{\xeval}$};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}               

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Both look good. Is there a way to remove decimal from second option? I do like the section option as it seems 'cleaner'.

Comment: @Calhistorian I updated my answer with a third option.

Comment: @Calhistorian I fixed the second option in my updated answer.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thanks. This third option is very clean. Cleanliness is important for me as my document will be edited by the uninformed at future dates.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Ok, one last question. What if I wanted to only display even or odd integers within the range. For instance, instead of 1,2,3,4,etc - it would go 2,4,6,8,etc?

Comment: @Calhistorian with the `\numexpr` approach:                         `\foreach \x 
in {1,2,...,9}
                        \draw (\x,-2pt) -- (\x,2pt) node [anchor=north,below=3pt] {$\scriptstyle\the\numexpr2*\x\relax$};` with the `evaluate` approach: `\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,precision=0}

                        \foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \xeval using 2*\x]
in {1,2,...,9}
                        \draw (\x,-2pt) -- (\x,2pt) node [anchor=north,below=3pt] {$\scriptstyle\pgfmathprintnumber{\xeval}$};`

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you parametrize your construction?

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes,backgrounds,arrows}

\newcommand{\solutionline}[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1pt,line cap=round,x=.5cm,y=.5cm]
    \edef\offset{\number\numexpr#1-1\relax}
    \clip (0,-0.8) rectangle (10,1);
    %   Inequality Line
    \draw   [<->,thick]     (0,0) -- (10,0);
    %   Tick Marks
    \foreach \x in {1,2,...,9}
      \draw (\x,-2pt) -- (\x,2pt) node [anchor=north,below=3pt]
        {$\scriptstyle\number\numexpr\x+\offset\relax$};
  \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
\solutionline{8}

\solutionline{5}

\end{document}
```

[image]