# Complex Count in \foreach for number line

Tags: tikz-pgf, counters, foreach

I am looking to create simple number lines. I have asked a similar question: [Resetting numerical labels in \foreach commands on a numberline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112821/resetting-numerical-labels-in-foreach-commands-on-a-numberline). But now I am in a different situation.

I know how to start the counting at a different number, but how can I count from a specific number by fives. For example: I want the number line to begin at 140, but count by 5's every x coordinate.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1pt,line cap=round,x=.5cm,y=.5cm]
                    \clip (0,-0.8) rectangle (10,1);
                    %   Inequality Line
                    \draw   [<->,thick]     (0,0) -- (10,0);
                    %   Tick Marks
                    \foreach \x in {1,2,...,9}
                    \draw (\x,-2pt) -- (\x,2pt) node [anchor=north,below=3pt] 
                    {$\scriptstyle \x$};
                    %   Displayed Solution
\end{tikzpicture}               
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can calculate the labels from your loop variable: `\pgfmathparse{int(140+5*(\x-1))}$\scriptstyle \pgfmathresult$`

Comment: Also you can tell the loop to do the computation for you with another variable `\foreach \x[evaluate=\x as \labelx using int(140+5*(\x-1))] in {1,2,...,9}{..... {$scriptstyle \labelx$};}`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are many ways for numerical calculations. The following example uses e-TeX's `\numexpr`:

```
\the\numexpr 135 + 5 * \x \relax
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1pt,line cap=round,x=.5cm,y=.5cm]
  \clip (0,-0.8) rectangle (10,1);
  %   Inequality Line
  \draw   [<->,thick]     (0,0) -- (10,0);
  %   Tick Marks
  \foreach \x in {1,2,...,9}
  \draw (\x,-2pt) -- (\x,2pt) node [anchor=north,below=3pt]
  {$\scriptstyle \the\numexpr135+5*\x\relax$};
  %   Displayed Solution
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Would it be possible to get a slight explanation of that command? `\the\numexpr135+5*\x\relax`. For instance what is `\relax`?

Comment: @Calhistorian: `\relax` is optional and tells `\numexpr` that the expression is finished. `\the` (also `\number` can be used instead) forces `\numexpr` to trigger the calculation and output the number. More details, see [The e-TeX Manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/e-tex/v2/doc/etex_man.pdf).

Comment: Excellent! I will get the manual. Didn't know about that one.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways for numerical calculations inside `\foreach` loop. Here are two possibilities, one use `count`, the other `evaluate` :

```
\documentclass[preview, border=7mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1pt,line cap=round,x=.5cm,y=.5cm]
    % axes
    \draw   [<->,thick]     (0,0) -- (10,0);
    % tick marks and numbers below
    \foreach[count=\x] \l in {140,145,...,180}
      \draw (\x,2pt) -- (\x,-2pt) node[blue, below,scale=.5]{$\l$};
    % numbers above
    \foreach[evaluate={\l=int(5*\x+135)}] \x in {1,...,9}
      \node[above,scale=.5,red] at (\x,2pt) {$\l$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]